# How to store unicode in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, unicode

How do I store Unicode in free edition of MySQL?

There doesn't seem to be `nvarchar` type as in SQL Server. Is Unicode not supported in MySQL? I tried using `text` but that too is not working.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to choose a  `utf8_*` character set for your table. Text and memo fields will then automatically be stored in UTF-8. Support for UTF-16 is coming in mySQL 6.

Comment: Update: UTF-16 & Emoji (utf8mb4) support is introduced since version 5.5: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode.html

Comment: It's worth noting that depending on how you retrieve the data from the database it might also be necessary to explicitly let the connection use UTF-8 as well.

Answer (score 28):

The character set for a given string column (`CHAR`, `VARCHAR` or `*TEXT`) is determined by its [**character set** and/or **collation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset.html). This is a quite intense topic so it's best to read the documentation I linked. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
    col1 CHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
)
```

will create a table `t1` with a `col1` that stores its content in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Nice explanation and example. Thanks.@Stefan Gehrig

Comment: The example is really helpful. Thank you Stefan :-)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting names after connection? What was the outcome of tryng to store unicode characters? Connect to mysql server and type this:

```
SET NAMES UTF8;
```

This should turn on "support" for utf8. Then try storing utf data.

Answer (score 2):

- MySQL [supports](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-mysql.html) UTF-8.
- Use varchar and set encoding for the column (it's quite easy in phpMyAdmin)

http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2006/01/turning_mysql_data_in_latin1_t.html - I think this could help you

Answer (score 2):

I follow my own style of coding, so please take that into account when following my lead.

First I created the MySql database.

after creating database, in mysql command prompt, give the command:

```
SET NAMES = UTF8;
```

table and columns to store unicode are to be set with collation property as utf8-utf_general_ci. Each and every column which meant to store unicode, is to be selected and set collation property to utf8-utf_general_ci.

Now in C#.

my connection string is set as usual but with addition of a single attribute like this:

```
constring = @"SERVER=localhost;" + @"PORT=3306;" + @"DATABASE=gayakidb;" + @"UID=root;" + @"PASSWORD=mysql;" + @"charset=utf8;";
```

Next, installed unicode font in the 'Display language setting' of your system OS. Or, you can copy and paste the font file (true type file) in the Fonts folder of Operating System.

Then I set the font property of the textbox object or any other tool object in property page.

More over, if you need to type in unicode font using your keyboard, you need to install the unicode language for keyboard layout. That could be done using the option for regional language settings of your Operating System.

Done. with these settings, i coded module for saving data and while running the ocde, it successfully done the work.

Answer (score 2):

Use this Query

```
alter table `DBNAME`.`TblName`  Engine=InnoDB checksum=1 comment='' delay_key_write=1 row_format=dynamic charset=utf8 collate=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: "Use this Query" without an explanation is a bad answer.