# ä stored as &#228; value is encoded in database

Tags: mysql, sql, unicode, asp-classic

I write out a variable on the asp page:

```
name="ända"
response.write name
```

It shows `ända` on the page, good!

When inserting it into the database, the value written to the database is `&#228;nda`

The page is encoded with `<%Response.charset="iso-8859-1"%>`

How can I get this value `ända` to be written to the database?

```
<%Response.charset="iso-8859-1"%>

folderName=request.querystring("foretagsnamn")

         folderName = replace(folderName, "å" , "a")
         folderName = replace(folderName, "ä" , "a")
         folderName = replace(folderName, "ö" , "o")
         folderName = replace(folderName, "Å" , "a")
         folderName = replace(folderName, "Ä" , "a")
         folderName = replace(folderName, "Ö" , "o")
         folderName = LCase(folderName)
        response.write folderName
```

And then just a sql insert to the database.

```
sql="INSERT INTO users(folderName) VALUES('"&folderName&"');"
    conn.execute(sql)
```

Its a mySql database, classic asp.

The querystring comes from a creditcard payment service, and the strange thing is that when I perform a transaction and I resive the querystring, it is wrong, but if I then just update the page so it runs the code and querystring again, it is right!?

Comment: What database server are you using and what does the code look like that you're using to write to the db?

Comment: Let's see your code that is doing the writing

Comment: At some point, your character is being converted into an HTML entity.  Like Joe Phillips said, we need to see the code to figure out where/why.

Comment: Is the column that you're putting the data into CHAR/VARCHAR or NCHAR/NVARCHAR?

Comment: Ahh - you'll need to change it to NVARCHAR to be able to store that character (it takes two bytes to store the binary value which in this case is 228).

Comment: I still don't know if that explains why it comes out as an HTML char

Comment: My advice: Drop the iso-8859-1 encodings in your database and website and go for UTF8 already, everywhere. My dayjob involves a website that made the mistake of using iso-8859-1 years ago, and not a day goes by where  we aren't kicking ourselves for that.

Comment: You should do something about the [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) in your code, **especially** since you're dealing with credit cards.

Comment: This code is vulnerable to sql injection

Answer (score 2):

URL parameters are URL-encoded, and you need to decode URL parameter values to get the original values.

For example, see this [implementation of URLDecode](http://www.aspnut.com/reference/encoding.asp)

In case of &#228;nda, this is HTML-encoded, and you find an HTML decoding function at the same address.

Not sure why you get an HTML encoded string as result of querystring().

Comment: I have asked the guy from where I get the querystring and he say that they send iso-8859-1, and when I look at the page souce and when I look at the page with response.write thevariable it looks right, but when it is inserted it gets wrong?

Comment: ã¶ is what I get when testing now?

Answer (score 1):

Ahh - use Bind Parameters instead of just concatenating your SQL statement together.  That solves a number of problems (performance, sql injection attacks, etc)

**EDIT:** I haven't played with MySQL in a while, but the idea is this:

```
command = new Command("INSERT INTO USERS(folderName) VALUES (@folderName)");

command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@folderName", DbType.NVarChar, 255, folderName));

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also, folderName must be a unicode column (NCHAR or NVARCHAR).

Comment: Sorry, but I dont know what Bind Parameters is.

Comment: I don't know if classic ASP even has bound parameters

Comment: I have allway used VARCHAR in the db, whats the difference?

Comment: VARCHAR uses a single byte to store a character and NVARCHAR (unicode) uses two bytes to store a character making it possible to store something with an ascii code of 228 (the character you're having problems with).

Comment: but if I try to change to NVARSCHAR in the db it wont take it, I get errornr 1064?

Comment: 1064 appears to indicate a syntax error in your sql statement.

Comment: I just took edit on the column and changed it to NVARCHAR(45)

Comment: Should I allways use NVARCHAR?

Comment: I tryed to make a new column with NVARCHAR but it still came out like VARCHAR, it wouldnt take it?

Comment: Ahh - sorry for my ignorance of MySql.  It looks like you have to set the collation of the table: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328968/how-can-i-store-unicode-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be passed via querystring as the wrong value. Where is the value coming from? That seems to be where the problem is being created.

Comment: But when I write the folderName variable on the page it is right. But then it gets wrong when it is inserted into the database.

Comment: When you look at the page are you looking at the source code or the page in a browser?

Comment: When I resive the querystring I write out the variable folderName on the page so I see it in the browser.

Comment: @Claes You need to view the page source and look at it there