# Python, ascii can't encode byte error

Tags: python, mysql

Hi I have an abstract that I download from a website, sometimes it doesn't have special chars and it doesn't give me any problem when I try to store it in the db...

Other times I get an error, Python can't encode byte error blah blah blah...

I use .encode('ascii', 'ignore') in order to avoid those issues but in the end those special characters don't get saved... what should I use to store every character without problems??

Comment: What encoding is the file you downloaded?

Comment: I don't download any file, I scrap a piece of text using scrapy and python from a website...

Answer (score 0):

As Alex mentioned, you first need to determine how the file is encoded (`response.encoding` in scrapy).  Assuming UTF-8, you'd simply `.encode('utf-8')`, or any of Python's other [supported encodings](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

You also need to make sure that the table in which you are trying to store the data accepts that particular encoding.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328968) for examples on how to enable UTF-8 storage.  You can also use any of the other [character sets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-charsets.html) that MySQL supports in the same manner.

Comment: Well, How can I know the enconding? As I mentioned I don't use a file to ge the abstract, I scrap them from a website using scrapy...

Comment: HTTP headers (and HTML headers) will often specify the encoding.  Scrapy records this in `response.encoding`.  You can even set a default for when an encoding isn't specified: http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?highlight=encoding#default-response-encoding

Comment: usually (but not always) the encoding is UTF-8 for web-related text.