# devnagri (hindi) font not getting stored in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to store devnagri (hindi) font in mysql but after the mysql insert is performed from browser which execute a php mysql insert code the result is

> à¤¹à¥‹à¤²à¥€ à¤•à¥‡ à¤¦à¥Œà¤°à¤¾à¤¨ à¤°à¤‚à¤—à¥‹à¤‚ à¤¸à¥‡
>   à¤–à¥‡à¤²à¤¨à¤¾ à¤”à¤° à¤¦à¥‹à¤¸à¥à¤¤à¥‹à¤‚ à¤•à¥‡ à¤¸à¤‚à¤—
>   à¤®à¤¸à¥à¤¤à¥€ à¤•à¤¿à¤¸à¥‡ à¤ªà¤¸à¤‚à¤¦ à¤¨à¤¹à¥€à¤‚à¥¤
>   à¤²à¥‡à¤•à¤¿à¤¨ à¤•à¥à¤¯à¤¾ à¤†à¤ª

trying to store

> अगर आपके शरीर में प्रोटीन की कमी है तो आपको बुढापे में मसूडों की
>   बीमारी हो सकती है। हालांकि मसूडों की समस्या किसी भी उम्र में हो सकती
>   है लेकिन प्रोटीन की कमी के कारण ज्यादातर मसूडों की समस्या बुढापे में
>   ही होती है। यदि शरीर में डेल-1 प्रोटीन का स्तर कम है तो बुढापे में
>   पेरियोडोंटाइटिस नामक मसूडों की बीमारी हो सकती हैं। इसमें मसूडों से खून
>   निकलता है और दांतों के आसपास की हड्डियां कमजोर हो जाती हैं। इस बीमारी
>   में मुंह के कीटाणुओं के प्रति अवरोधक तंत्र ज्यादा सक्रिय हो जाता है।

when i insert these details directly in mysql row through phpmyadmin i am able to store the hindi font
structure of the table is

```
   type text
   collation    utf8_unicode_ci
```

my mysql insert code is

```
 mysql_query ("INSERT INTO tablea (tips) VALUES ('$tips') ");
```

Comment: Are you storing it as UTF-8? Are you **displaying** it as UTF-8?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams i think i am doing as utf-8 but how to verify

Comment: maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198701/storing-and-displaying-unicode-string-using-php-and-mysql?rq=1

Comment: @Thilo tried not working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328968/how-can-i-store-unicode-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
define('SQL_HOST','databasehost');
define('SQL_USER','user');
define('SQL_PASS','password');
define('SQL_DB','databasename');
$conn = mysql_connect(SQL_HOST, SQL_USER, SQL_PASS) or die('Could not connect to the database; ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(SQL_DB, $conn) or die('Could not select database; ' . mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Using `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` takes care of UTF-8. It worked for Devanagari in my case.

Do not forget to mention the same encoding in the meta tag

```
< meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```