# how to change font in mysql database to store unicode charactors

Tags: mysql, database, unicode

I want to store Unicode characters in mysql database what should i do.
I tried using charset settings but not working. please tell me some procedure to achive this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to choose a utf8_* character set for your table. Text and memo fields will then automatically be stored in UTF-8. Support for UTF-16 is coming in mySQL 6.
its answered in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328968/how-can-i-store-unicode-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

"not working" would be improved with an example of the code, input and output / error. The MySQL reference manual talks about this too.

Answer (score 0):

**Just save the data in hexadecimal form**

I am using java language and Eclipse and it will show the characters in ??? form. To solve this program, click project->resources->other and select language as `UTF-8.`
And also add the line as 
`String hindiStr = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(iFrmCity);`

Here `ifrmCity` is a string retrieve the data from database which will be in form of ???

This solution will work not only for Hindi, this can be used for any language to retrieve from db.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE DATABASE hindi_test
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

USE hindi_test;

CREATE TABLE `hindi` (
`data` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `hindi` (`data`) VALUES
('कंप्यूटर');
```

Try this one will help you

Answer (score -2):

`CREATE DATABASE hindi_test
    CHARACTER SET utf8
    COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`

`USE hindi_test;`

`CREATE TABLE`hindi`(`
data`varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;`

`INSERT INTO`hindi`(`data`) VALUE ('कंप्यूटर');`