# Non-English characters count more with MySQL VARCHAR?

Tags: mysql, arabic, varchar

Doesn't VARCHAR(15) mean you can have up to 15 *characters* in the field? If so, why am I getting 'Data too long' error?

I insert my data as **123456789** with no problem,

but with **١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩** I get

`Data too long for column 'customer_phone' at row 1`

they have the same number of characters!

My table definition (partly):

`+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+--------------+
| Field             | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra         |
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+---------------+
| id                | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment|
| customer_id       | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL              |               |
| customer_name     | varchar(75)   | YES  |     | NULL              |               |
| customer_phone    | varchar(15)   | YES  |     | NULL              |               |
| paid_amount       | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NULL              |               |
| paid_currency     | varchar(4)    | NO   | MUL | NULL              |               |
| ex_rate           | decimal(8,2)  | NO   |     | NULL              |               |
| date_time         | datetime      | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |               |
| is_virtual        | tinyint(1)    | NO   |     | 0                 |               |
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+---------------+`

Comment: use the lenght() function to find the string real lenght

Comment: I just have, hope you'll be of help :)

Comment: What is your character set ? example : show create table table_name;

Answer (score 1):

According to [phpwact.org](http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/charsets)

> ... UTF-8 is a multibyte 8-bit encoding in which each Unicode scalar
>   value is mapped to a sequence of one to four bytes. ...

Briefly, when you use utf8 your string can include characters with one to four bytes. I think english characters take one byte while Arabic / Persian characters take two bytes.

When you use varchar(N) it means you can insert N bytes. It means you can have N/2 arrabic characters inserted.

**Conclusion** : If you want insert a string with (N) Arabic / Persian characters then you must choose varchar(2*N).

Please let me know if this works, and what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you set your connection character set to UTF8 prior to running the insertion query

you have to change the length of your column `varchar(30)` or change the collation to UTF8

```
  ALTER TABLE mytable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: what do you mean by connection character set? I set it through `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8')` if that's what you mean?

Comment: you go to your database and change the collation of that column to UTF8

Comment: the collation is `utf8_general_ci` and why would I need to set to `varchar(30)` if that realy means number of "characters" rather than some byte size?

Comment: to change to varchar(30) is just an option i said

Comment: I had already done that, but that's just strange! I shouldn't need to do that. even thou it does the job, I shall know why?

Comment: as i know , utf8 characters are counted double , you have to set utf8 collation. everywhere , your column , your editor , your files...

Comment: my Arabic is very bad, but I understood your message :) I have set everything to utf8 but I think unicode characters must be counted as double !

Comment: You need to choose a utf8_* character set for your table. try my updated answer.

Comment: check  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328968/how-can-i-store-unicode-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Find the character set and make sure is set to UTF8. 
 **to do so just add the follwing into your my.cnf file**

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```