# Rails, strange string insert into database. How to escape everything?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, string, escaping

sometimes I have to insert some strange things to db, example:

```
SET `title` = '\"- ✪㉨)⊃ [PC] 1# Potato(ง ͠ ᵒ̌ Дᵒ̌)\"'
```

Error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x8A\x82(\xE2\x9C...' for column 'title' at row 1
```

My ActiveRecord code:

```
@title = "- ✪㉨)⊃ [PC] 1# Potato(ง ͠ ᵒ̌ Дᵒ̌)\"

User.update(1, title: "#{@title.inspect}") # .inspect doesn't help :/
```

What I think I can do is that that I can create table with wierdo signs like `✪` or `㉨` and replace them in string with some code before saving. And replace some code with these signs after selecting this string from database. But... its basically impossible to catch everything...

Comment: Seems like a problem with [collations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-charsets.html). Which collations do you using for DB and tables?

Comment: have you tried unicode.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328968/how-to-store-unicode-in-mysql

Comment: Changed to utf-8 from latin1 and it seems to be working. Thanks guys :)