# NHibernate not saving Urdu Language text

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am using nhibernate with asp.net 4.0 
And want to save Urdu Language text to database .
But not saving that 
Save the text as "????????"

But works fine every thing else

Just wondering that how could it save urdu text to database

This is my nhibernate configuration file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
<session-factory>
<property name="dialect">
  NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect
</property>

<property name="connection.provider">
    NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
</property>

<property name="connection.driver_class">
      NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver
</property>

<property name="connection.connection_string">
  Server=localhost;Database=db_opdsoft;User ID=root;Password=root
</property>

<mapping assembly="OPDSoft"></mapping>

</session-factory>
```

Comment: can you post your sql-query to work with that?

Comment: saving using ISession.save()

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify in the mapping that the string property should be saved to a column with a type supporting Unicode and the database/table has to be set to unicode [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3328984/671619)