# How to insert Hindi language to mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, hindi

I want to insert Hindi language sentences to mysql database.
But I encountered a problem: Hindi language sentences that are inserted into mysql database has become garbled. 
I have set the encoding format to UTF-8, then my code is as follows. 
Thanks a lot!

```
#coding = utf-8

import MySQLdb
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')


dbs = MySQLdb.connect(host='x.x.x.x', user='x', passwd = 'x', db='x',port=x)
cursor = dbs.cursor()

with open('hindi.wiki.set','r') as file:
    count = 1
    for line in file.readlines():
        if count == 5:
            break
        sql = """insert into `lab_ime_test_set_2` (id_, type_, lang_, text_, anno_) values(%s, %s, %s,'%s', %s)""" % ("null", "'wiki'", "'hindi'", MySQLdb.escape_string(line.strip()), "'not_anno'")
        try:
            cursor.execute(sql)
            dbs.commit()
        except Exception as eh:
            print("error")
    print("total count", count)
    cursor.close()
    dbs.close()
```

since the sql can bu run in navicat for mysql and the hindi language can be shown correctly.
But when I run this code, the sentences can be inserted in mysql database as well, but can't be shown correctly.
such as "à¤¸à¤‚à¤¤à¤°à¥‡ à¤•à¥‡ à¤œà¤¾à¤¯à¤•à¥‡ à¤µà¤¾à¤²à¥‡ à¤®à¥‚à¤² à¤Ÿà¥ˆà¤‚à¤— à¤•à¥‹ 1957 à¤®à¥‡à¤‚ à¤œà¤¨à¤°à¤² à¤«à¥‚à¤¡à¥à¤¸ à¤•à¥‰à¤°à¤ªà¥‹à¤°à¥‡à¤¶à¤¨ à¤•à¥‡ à¤²à¤¿à¤ à¤µà¤¿à¤²à¤¿à¤¯à¤® à¤"

Comment: use Collation utf8-general-ci in mysql

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328968/how-to-store-unicode-in-mysql#3328984