# Insert special characters (ą, ź, etc.) into varchar column via Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I'm trying to [insert](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core-example.html) some strings with special characters into  my database using Entity Framework 6, but it seems EF changes them while putting into DB. For example, "zażółć gęślą jaźń" becomes "zazólc gesla jazn".
I want to insert my data unchanged and keep my column as varchar.
I've tried some annotations and executing command that alters collation and character set after creating DB, however these attempts have failed.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.DataAnnotations;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var context = new TestDBContext())
        {
            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            // tried this
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                "ALTER DATABASE `TestDB` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci");
            context.insertData();
            // result: "lódz" - doesn't work either
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                "INSERT INTO `testtable` (`Id`, `SpecialCharacters`) VALUES (NULL, 'łódź')");
        }
    }
}

class TestDBContext : DbContext
{
    public Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<TestTable> TestTable { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("server=localhost;database=TestDB;user=root;password=;SslMode=None;");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<TestTable>()
            .HasKey(t => t.Id);
    }

    // result: "zazólc gesla jazn" instead of "zażółć gęślą jaźń"
    public void insertData()
    {
        using (var context = new TestDBContext())
        {
            context.TestTable.Add(new TestTable
                {
                    SpecialCharacters = "zażółć gęślą jaźń",
                }
            );
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

class TestTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(17)")]
    [MySqlCharset("utf8")] // tried this
    [MySqlCollation("utf8_unicode_ci")] // tried this
    public string SpecialCharacters { get; set; }
}
```

(Note `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO...` also violates the data. Adding such data via console (without EF) works just fine.)
Finally, my question: how to insert strings with special characters into varchar column in DB using Entity Framework?

Comment: Varchar cannot represent all unicode characters. Can you not alter the column to be nvarchar?

Comment: `want to insert my data unchanged and keep my column as varchar.` You can have one or the other, but not both. If you want the former - use `nvarchar`. If you want to use `varchar` then the former isn't possible.

Comment: You should tag your question `mysql` if it concerns a MySQL database, which appears to be the case. You're getting comments on the assumption that SQL Server is involved... MySQL, of course, *has* no `NVARCHAR` type.

Comment: Have you tried adding `charset=utf8` to your connection string (per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20537841/4137916))?

Comment: @JeroenMostert solution works perfectly. Changing connection string did the trick. Indeed, I should've included MySQL tag. To sum up: to make your DB accept special characters, include `charset=utf8` in connection string and add one or both of the following annotation for the given column: `[MySqlCharset("utf8")]` and/or `[MySqlCollation("utf8_unicode_ci")]`. Thanks for all answers and editing.