# How can I change/create a table to support fancy text (unicode)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I am trying to store this value in my database . However, when I insert it into my database, it shows up blank. Other non-fancy text is inserted just fine, but it messes up on fancy text/unicode. I wanted to know, how I can change a table to support all kinds of text (every text possible).

I am using phpmyadmin

```
INSERT INTO users
(name, display_name)
VALUES ("Mike", "");
```

---

The collation is set to `utf8_unicode_ci`

The **default character set** of the database is `utf8`

The **default character collation** is `utf8_unicode_ci`

---

This is how I create my table

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id         int(6)
                    NOT NULL
                    AUTO_INCREMENT
                    PRIMARY KEY,

    name            varchar(64)
                    NOT NULL,

    display_name    varchar(256)
                    NOT NULL
);
```

---

I can create a new users table, but I cannot create a new database as there are lots of tables in the database which I cannot delete (as they have lots of data in them already)

Comment: look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328968/how-to-store-unicode-in-mysql

Comment: @Ani My database is already created though. My Collation is `utf8_unicode_ci` Isn't there a way to change it?

Comment: The collation isn't as important as the encoding. Do you use `utf8mb4`?

Comment: @tadman Sorry, I'm kind of a noob. How can I check that? Also I updated what I used to create the table

Comment: For MySQL: `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Comment: @Kiwa, you have to do `show create table users;` in mysql, that outputs more info about the table, and add the result to the question.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL may not support NVARCHAR, but I believe the key word "NATIONAL" can be used instead, so your table definition for this column would become:

```
display_name national varchar(256) not null
```

Credit to https://lists.mysql.com/mysql/116585 Here's the critical info:

```
mysql> create table bb(
    -> name NATIONAL VARCHAR(10));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

If NVARCHAR doesn't work then I suspect an older version of MySQL because according to their latest documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-national.html these are all equivalent (note the 3rd option):

```
VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8
NATIONAL VARCHAR(10)
NVARCHAR(10)
NCHAR VARCHAR(10)
NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(10)
NATIONAL CHAR VARYING(10)
```

Note: nvarchar / national varchar uses twice the storage space (2 bytes per character) so use it only when you need to store uni-code characters.

Comment: Wow, I learned something. I always thought MySQL was compliant with SQL-92, but it looks like you're right. I'll update my answer.

Comment: And National varchar translates to varchar... No the answer to that question is to create a varchar column with the utf8mb4 encoding (utf8 is not enough).