# Unable to insert square root string in my mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, mariadb

I want to insert similar text into mysql table.
It is inserted in table but it insert like **42=(-4)2=16** ..
I want to insert it properly with square root symbol.
I guess MySQL proper collation type might be the solution but don't know which collation it may work.

[image]

Comment: I'd say it would make sense if you describe what encoding and collation you are using right now. So that one can work from there. How did you make sure that it is the database engine that alters the string and not some other aspect like your application logic or the visualization layer?

Comment: i have tried utf8_general_ci, utf8_unicode_ci, and utf8_bin collation types. but none worked.
i am assuming because i am directly inserting data from the square rooted text formatted string from any other pages and paste it into phpmyadmin insert statement then also it rearrange it to>> 42=(-4)2=16 <<these format

Answer (score 0):

As you described you tried the right collation (utf8_unicode_ci), it is not a MySQL issue. You may see the previous discussion on [how to store unicode in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328968/how-to-store-unicode-in-mysql) on stackoverflow.

Following these answers, I executed the followed queries:

```
CREATE TABLE can_square ( sqr CHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci);

INSERT INTO can_square (sqr) VALUES ( "4² = (-4)² = 16" );
```

And it works fine.

And I inserted the same type of data from my PHPMyAdmin successfully, both from running an SQL query and inserting manually in the insert tab. Then it also is not a PHPMyAdmin issue

As yourself spotted, its probably a string formatting issue when you copy and paste from another source. Try to type the string directly in PHPMyAdmin and see if it works. If you have to put the value manually, and you know it is happening, copy and paste may not be a good alternative.