# How to store emoji in MySQL database table

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL(5.6) database and want to store emoji in the database table. When I try to insert any emoji I am not getting any error but instead of emoji one question mark(?) is getting inserted. The data type of column is longtext. Below are the  character set at column and  table level:

Table - CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
Column -  charset utf8mb4;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store unicode in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328968/how-to-store-unicode-in-mysql)

Comment: Also see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463134/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-mysql-database)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store Emoji Character in MySQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463134/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-mysql-database)