# How do I import dump file containing "£" data into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, utf-8

I'm trying to create a dump file from an MSAccess database to import in to a MySQL database. I can create the dump file, but when I try to import it I get this error **`Incorrect string value: '\xA325- R...' for column...`**

I'm not really sure what it means or how to fix it. I know the dump partially works as other tables and data get imported. The import gets to this error and then stops

I've tried setting this `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;` on the table
I've also tried this on the column `CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci`

Here's an example from my dump file

```
CREATE TABLE Agent_Table(
    AgentID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    Agent VARCHAR(255) ,
    Archive VARCHAR(255) ,
    AgentEmail VARCHAR(255) ,
    AgentMobile VARCHAR(255) , 
PRIMARY KEY (`AgentID`)
)
```

I also tried

```
CREATE TABLE Agent_Table(
    AgentID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    Agent VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
    Archive VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ,
    AgentEmail VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
    AgentMobile VARCHAR(255)CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`AgentID`)
)

DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```

I've tried a number of the utf8 options as well and still no joy

Nothing seems to work.

I'm writing a dump file because I've exhausted all other methods to try and to import/export the data

All the methods/tools I have tried all fail with some form of ODBC error I'd list them here but there are so many as I have been at this all day.

If anyone knows how to fix this problem or how else I can import this data I would appreciate it

**UPDATE**

The problems are £ and ` and ’ that I have seen so far. If I do a find and replace of those chars they no longer throw up errors. But it seems no matter what encoding I set the database to it just does not like these characters during the import.

Comment: Edit question to show sample data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store unicode in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328968/how-to-store-unicode-in-mysql)

Comment: Your dump file from Access is almost certainly not UTF-8 encoded. It's most likely "ANSI" (Windows-1252) encoded, where 0xA3 is `£`. (If it was Unicode it would probably use UTF-16LE encoding.) When importing your dump file into MySQL, specify that the file is Windows-1252 encoded and see if that helps.

Comment: @GordThompson You are probably correct, but as I'm dumping from VBA the encoding options are very limited

Comment: There are options for changing the encoding of a table export (e.g., to CSV) on the Access side, but they are not immediately obvious. Still, I have to imagine that there is a way to specify the file encoding when you come to do the import. What tool are you using for that?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am creating the dump file manually and the only option is to unicode or not. To import the file I'm using the Import function of MySQL WorkBench or phpMyAdmin, same issues with both

Comment: So you're creating a file with DDL (CREATE TABLE) and DML (INSERT INTO) similar to what `mysqldump` produces?

Comment: Yes thats correct. If I remove anything unicode the dump file is imported with no issues

Comment: So when you go to import the dump file using phpMyAdmin do you not have the option to specify the character set of the file, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH8dx.png)?